# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69) a

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber

I have written a code for login page but here i'm getting "nullPointerException". Anyone's help would be better. Thanks in advance.
[LoginPgae.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwyHa.png)
[LoginStepDef.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlgKO.jpg)
[BaseClass.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/166Pf.jpg)`enter code here`

Getting error as
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.click(Unknown Source)
    at Pages.LoginPage.login_To_AdminPannel(LoginPage.java:35)
    at StepDefinition.LoginStepDef.user_logsIn(LoginStepDef.java:28)

Comment: Provide your base class

Comment: Added base class. Please check

Comment: In `LoginStepDef` class you initialize `LoginPage` class before invoking `BaseClass.initialization()` method which causes the `null` WebDriver

Comment: Thank you @Fenio. I have made changes accordingly and It worked

Comment: @sheena Glad to help. Good job on the fix

Answer (score 0):

So in your code, You are trying to invoke your Page object model before you initialize your drivers because of this you are getting NullPointerException. 
if you call your base class initialization before handling LoginPage will resolve your issue.